How to initialize member std::variant variable based on the input of the constructor
I have a class BASE which contains a member variable of type std::variant which can contain an object of type A or B. Based on the input to the constructor at runtime, I want to initialize this variable to contain either A or B (calling their constructors with an input).
Something along these lines:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

class A {
private:
    char* arr;
public:
    A() = default;
    A(int n) {
        arr = new char[3];
        arr[0] = arr[1] = arr[2] = 'A';
        std::cout << "Constructor A called with " + std::to_string(n);
        std::cout << " [" << arr[0] << "," << arr[1] << "," << arr[2] << "]" << std::endl; 
    }
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "Destructor A called";
        std::cout << " [" << arr[0] << "," << arr[1] << "," << arr[2] << "]" << std::endl; 
        delete[] arr;
    }
};
class B {
private:
    char* arr;
public:
    B() = default;
    B(int n) {
        arr = new char[3];
        arr[0] = arr[1] = arr[2] = 'B';
        std::cout << "Constructor B called with " + std::to_string(n);
        std::cout << " [" << arr[0] << "," << arr[1] << "," << arr[2] << "]" << std::endl; 
    }
    ~B() {
        std::cout << "Destructor B called ";
        std::cout << " [" << arr[0]  << "," << arr[1] << "," << arr[2] << "]" << std::endl; 
        delete[] arr;
    }
};


class BASE {
private: 
     std::variant<A, B> myVar;

public:
     BASE() = delete;
     BASE(int i) {
         if (i == 0) {
             std::cout << "Initializing A" << std::endl;
             myVar = A(i);
         } else {
             std::cout << "Initializing B" << std::endl;
             myVar = B(i);
         }
     }
};

int main() {
    BASE test1(0);
}

This however does not work, since right after the assignment to myVar, the destructor of A (or B) is called and myVar contains garbage.
See: https://onlinegdb.com/t3oK456_w
I thought I could initialize it in a list at the constructor, something like this:
BASE(int i) :
    myVar(i == 0 ? A("input.txt") : B("input.txt"))
{
}

but that (of course) does not work neither.
I appreciate any hint how to do it properly (ideally in C++17). Thanks

Please post a [mre] including A and B (a minimal version of them that enables to reproduce the problem).

@wohlstad added.

The destructor you see is the one of the temporary created in assignments like myVar = A(i);. myVar should still have a valid value after the assignment and not garbage as you wrote.

@PeteBecker I edited the text slightly. Yes, myVar can hold an object of type either A or B (based on how I initialize the BASE object).

Continuing my previous comment - as you can see in this demo the variant contains valid values.

"and myVar contains garbage" How do you know that?

@HolyBlackCat Here is a modified example: https://onlinegdb.com/t3oK456_w

@wohlstad I modified the example little bit (such that it contains some dynamic memory allocation). https://onlinegdb.com/t3oK456_w

That A is poorly written, it needs to implement at least a copy constructor and a copy assignment, and preferably a move constructor and a move assignment too. As written, it'll break in many other scenarios too, like A x; A y = x; (after this x contains junk, and will likely crash in the destructor when freeing the same memory again).

To continue @HolyBlackCat's comment: it doesn't respect the rule of 0/3/5. This causes e.g. a double-free, and the problem is not related to the std::variant.

@wohlstad OK, I see the problems. Why does it then work when the variable is initialized in the constructor list,
```?
In that case the destructor is called only once when the base object gets destroyed.

Because this doesn't try to copy A. When anything whatsoever tries to copy it, it breaks.

If you have only one object (because you don't have the temporary) the root problem mentioned above does manifest, but it is still there.

Does this answer your question? What is The Rule of Three?

One more suggestion concerning your approach: Use cout << this to output the address of the object, which is a unique identifier for its lifetime. That way, you would have seen better which object gets created and destroyed.

Avoiding manual memory management would avoid that issue, i.e, in your case, simply use std::string (or don't use it at all, it is a constant string which doesn't need to be a non-static member).

Look carefully at the output of your program (https://www.onlinegdb.com/KRvUQU7vm):

Initializing A
Constructor A called with 0
Destructor A called
Initializing B
Constructor B called with 1
Destructor A called
Destructor B called
Destructor B called
Destructor A called

Do you see that after "Constructor B called with 1" there's a "Destructor A called"? Where does it come from?
The answer is that your class BASE contains std::variant<A, B> myVar;, and the constructor of BASE must initialize it before the body of the constuctor is run. To do it, it chooses the first type of the variant, that is, A, which is default constructed. If you modify the default constructors to
A() {
    std::cout << "Default constructor of A\n";
}

and likewise for B, you'll see that when you create the 2 BASE objects (test1 and test2) there's a call to the default constructor of A before it even prints "Initializing A".
Change the variant to std::variant<B, A> myVar; (switching the order of the types) and you'll see two calls to B's default constructor. But myVar does not contain garbage!
In your other example (https://onlinegdb.com/t3oK456_w), which uses new[] and delete[], there's a double-free error because the default constructor does not call new[], but the destructor still calls delete[]. And that's why the result is garbage.
So the way you use the constructor of BASE to decide which type to use in the variant is correct. The problem is that there's a "hidden" call to the default constructor of the first type (A), which must behave correctly.
